# Toggle low state won't be sent to python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi, togglebutton

I'm trying to send the state of a bootstrap toggle button to a python cgi script. It works fine when the toggle is true (python script prints "true") but when false, the python script prints "None" as if the input value I try to send was empty.

The `console.log(tgl_state);` prints the state of the toggle with no problem in both cases (true and false).

Can you tell me where I'm wrong ? Thanks !

Here is the html code :

```
    <div style="display:block;"> 
      <iframe id="python_result" name="python_result"></iframe> 
    </div>

    <div>

      <form id="tgleq"  method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/radio_test.py" target="python_result">
      <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" name="toggle-event" value="TOTO">
      </form>

        <script>
                            $(function() {
                              $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
                              tgl_state = $('#toggle-event').prop("checked")

                            console.log(tgl_state);    
                            var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle-event");

                            toggle.value = tgl_state;
                            document.getElementById("tgleq").submit();
                              })
                            })

        </script>
    </div>
```

And here is the python script (radio_test.py), just printing what comes from the web interface :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import socket

cgitb.enable()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

form=cgi.FieldStorage()

arg1 = form.getvalue('toggle-event')
print arg1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how HTML forms work: if a checkbox is unticked, its value is not sent in the POST data.

This shouldn't be a problem though; it just means that the result of `form.getvalue('toggle-event')` is either "TOTO" or None.

Comment: Okay... So, how can I perform action then, when toggle is low ?

Comment: Why not `if  form.getvalue('toggle-event') is None`?

Comment: Thanks ! It works fine. I was trying to do ‘if arg1 == "None"‘ so it didn't work, of course...!